# Node is working on mac but not in ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

The same line of code was working in mac but not in ubuntu. To elaborate, the expected behavior is collection gets updated according to the newly set values but it didn't happen when I ran this script in an ubuntu server, but in my local mac it worked, with the same db configuration. Anyone faced anything similar?

- Node v12.6.0
- mongoClient v5.3.0

```
 let db;        
 MongoClient.connect(DATABASE_URI_LIVE, {
 useNewUrlParser: true,
 useUnifiedTopology: true,
 poolSize: 10,
        connectTimeoutMS: 0,
        socketTimeoutMS: 0,
        }, (err, client) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        db = client.db(DATABASE_NAME) 
        elements.forEach(element => {
            if (element._id && element.rate) {
               db.collection('InvoiceItem').updateOne({ _id: element._id }, { $set: { rate: 
                                      element.rate } }, (err,res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    console.log('ta-da')
                })

            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Consider adding the error you are seeing.

Comment: there were no errors at all, I just added a console before the update query to make sure it's reaching there and it did.

Comment: Consider specifying what is not working.

Comment: okay.. my bad, the expected behavior is collection gets updated according to the new set values but it didn't happen when I ran this script in an ubuntu server but in my local mac it worked, with the same db configuration.

Comment: You can try by promisify or async/await the code instead of using a callback, it's support in your MongoDb Node.js driver version.

Comment: wow it worked.. thank you so much